# Select box magento

Tags: magento

I have select box with two values, Metric and Imperial. Depending on what I choose, runs the logic that I have in the controller:

```
public function multiplyAction() {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('measurement') == 'imperial') {
            return Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMeasurement('imperial');
        } elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('measurement') == 'metric') {
            return Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMeasurement('metric');
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Controller working right, but it's must just return values and skip rendering, instead it's go on URL: .../switcher/switcher/multiply/

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('measurementswitcher/switcher/multiply'); ?>">
            <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="measurement" title="<?php echo $this->__('Preferred units') ?>" id="select-metric">
                <option value="imperial" id="imperial" <?php if ( Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMeasurement() === "imperial" ) : ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo "Imperial (inch, gallon)" ?></option>
                <option value="metric" id="metric" <?php if ( Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMeasurement() === "metric" ) : ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo "Metric (mm, liter)" ?></option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Maybe I'm doing it all wrong? Or miss some important part? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the hidden `formkey` value.

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

also check for you url post is working perfect or not.

hope this will sure help you.